# How to pair each column in the list form in pandas by Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['an apple is red', 'pop is here'],['pear  is green', 'see is blue']], columns=['A', 'B']
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
df['A'] = [TweetTokenizer().tokenize(text) for text in df['A']]
df['id']=[1,2]
for k in df['A']:
    print(k)
    pid = df[df['A']==k]['id'].values[0]
    ['an', 'apple', 'is', 'red']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-156-f9e4fa5143b0> in <module>
      1 for k in df['A']:
      2     print(k)
----> 3     pid = df[df['A']==k]['id'].values[0]

~/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
   1743             # as it will broadcast
   1744             if other.ndim != 0 and len(self) != len(other):
-> 1745                 raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
   1746 
   1747             res_values = na_op(self.values, np.asarray(other))

ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

I want to get the pid when k is equal to each row of column A.
I can make it through when each row is string. How to do it when each row is a list?

once matching, I get the corresponding value of 'id'

expected pid out put:
1
2

Comment: Can you port your expected output?

Comment: Your `df['A']` is a series `0    [an, apple, is, red]
1       [pear, is, green]` with list. You need to iterate through the list again in order to get each item in the list. Is that what you are expecting?

Comment: Can you compare by converting Column A value to string like : ```df[df['A'].str.contains(k)]``` or ```df.loc[df['A'] == k]```?

Comment: @UserAG I got 1st method:TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' and 2nd method: ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

Comment: explain what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code and it is returning the pid correctly as per your question.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['an apple is red', 'pop is here'],['pear  is green', 'see is blue']], columns=['A', 'B'])
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
df['A'] = [TweetTokenizer().tokenize(text) for text in df['A']]
df['id']=[1,2]
for k in df['A']:
    print(k)
    pid = df[df['A'].map(tuple)==tuple(k)]['id'].values[0]
    print(pid)
```

Since `list` comparison are messy in `dataframe`, it is better to convert the column values to `tuple` and then do the comparison.

You can also look into getting the index of `dataframe` rows while iterating if you need just index of each row here.